# Interpolating curves whose x ranges are contained in the x range of another curve (Python)

Tags: python, interpolation, extrapolation

I have two sets of data points, `set1` and `set2`, each of which contains two columns of `x` and `y` values, like that (for one of them, the other has similar structure and values)

```
x            y

0.015        0.01
0.025        0.015
..           ..
0.115        0.07
```

so that we have an `x` axis that scales in steps of `0.01`, while `y` is random. Then I have a third set, `set3`, which looks this way

```
x           y

0.025       0.2
0.075       0.1
...         ...
3.475       0.005
```

so the increment is `x` is again constant and in this case equal to `0.05`, while `y` is again random. The range in `x` of `set3` is much wider than `set1` and `set2`.

My goal is to have three sets that span the same range in x.

To do so, I though about interpolating the two shorter sets, `set1` and `set2`, whose x ranges are contained in `set3`'s one.

I did it (for `set1` for example, analogously for `set2`), using

```
import scipy.interpolate as itp
spline_set1 = itp.splrep(xvalues_set1, yvalues_set1)
extended_set1 = itp.splev(xvalues_set3, spline_set1)
```

but a plot of `extended_set1` looks as if this is not the way to go. The values are too high, many orders of magnitude bigger than they should be.

Any ideas?

Comment: I just tried the `splrep` on my own data and honestly I don't quite get how it works and what output it produces. For spline interpolation I always use `scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline`. This usually works pretty well and you could give it a try. Secondly I don't understand your desired output.An interpolation of set1 and set2 will just narrow the spaces between your x-values and y-values accordingly (i.e. you fill in the gaps). But if `set3` has a wider range, an interpolation of `set1` and `set2` is not going to help you for the values they don't contain themselves. What's your desired result?

Comment: @offeltoffel thanks, that's indeed a good point. In fact I think what I am looking for is extrapolation rather than interpolation. What I want is to have values for set1 and set2 that are defined on the same range of x values for set3. Which I think should be done by extrapolation, as the x ranges of set1 and set2 are smaller and contained in the x range of set3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your answer to my comment and assuming you are looking for extrapolation rather than interpolation:

Basically, you are creating information that is not there. Any extrapolation is based on your knowledge about the behavior of `y` in relation to `x`. The y3-values are unimportant in this case (which is why you did not need them in your own solution).

The basic tool for spline interpolation is `scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline` or `scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline` likewise. Both are able to extrapolate. In your case, it works like that:

```
import scipy.interpolate as itp
spline = itp.UnivariateSpline(xvalues_set1, yvalues_set1)
extended_set1 = spline(xvalues_set3)
```

However, the result could remain questionable. The behaviour of a spline-extrapolation might seem unrationable while still being mathematically correct. If you want to understand what's going on, I suggest you plot your result using `matplotlib.pyplot`.